# Calling a function in a view controller from another view controller

Tags: swift, view, controllers

Here is the code with the delegate process suggested...

in main view controller...

```
protocol FilterDelegate: class {
    func onRedFilter()
    func onGreenFilter()
    func onBlueFilter()
    func onUnfiltered()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, FilterDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

----

// Increase red color level on image by one.
    func onRedFilter() {

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "filterSegue" {

            let dest = segue.destinationViewController as!    CollectionViewController
            dest.filterDelegate = self

        }
    }
```

in collection view controller...

```
var filterDelegate: FilterDelegate?
```

---

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")

    guard let filterDelegate = filterDelegate else {
        print("Filter delegate wasn't set!")
        return
        }

    switch indexPath.row {

        case 0:
            filterDelegate.onRedFilter()
        case 1:
            filterDelegate.onGreenFilter()
        case 2:
            filterDelegate.onBlueFilter()
        case 3:
            filterDelegate.onUnfiltered()
        default:
            print("No available filter.")

    }
```

Right now...the code stops at the guard block and prints the error message. The switch block is not executed on any press of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your theory in your second last sentence is correct - when you call `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` in the "child" view controller, you are actually creating an entirely new instance of your main view controller. You are **not** getting a reference to the existing main view controller, which is why the methods you're calling are not having any effect.

There are several ways to achieve what you're trying to do, including the [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or using closures. Here's a sketch of what it could look like using a delegate protocol:

```
protocol FilterDelegate: class {
    func onRedFilter()
    func onGreenFilter()
    func onBlueFilter()
    func onUnfiltered()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController, FilterDelegate {

    // implement these as required
    func onRedFilter() { }
    func onGreenFilter() { }
    func onBlueFilter() { }
    func onUnfiltered() { }

    // when we segue to the child view controller, we need to give it a reference
    // to the *existing* main view controller
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? ChildViewController {
            dest.filterDelegate = self
        }
    }

}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    var filterDelegate: FilterDelegate?

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // ... 

        guard let filterDelegate = filterDelegate else {
            print("Filter delegate wasn't set!")
            return
        }

        switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                filterDelegate.onRedFilter()
            case 1:
                filterDelegate.onGreenFilter()
            case 2:
                filterDelegate.onBlueFilter()
            case 3:
                filterDelegate.onUnfiltered()
            default:
                print("No available filter.")

        }

    }

}
```

Another option would be to provide closures on `ChildViewController` for every function on `MainViewController` that the child needs to call, and set them in `prepareForSegue`. Using a delegate seems a bit cleaner though since there are a bunch of functions in this case.

Comment: I tried this and not only do the cells not call the filters (not even the embedded print statements that print the indexPath.row that was working), but now the horizontal scrolling of the collectionviewcontroller is broken. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like something got messed up with the child view controller, and the UICollectionViewDataSource methods aren't working. Without seeing the code it's tough to say what's going on. I guess I'd make sure it's still subclassing UICollectionViewController (not UIViewController), and make sure the data source is still  hooked up correctly in the storyboard.

Comment: Well I managed to get it back so the scrolling collection view is working. Can you explain to me what the block with the guard does and whether something is missing? Right now its printing the "Filter delegate wasn't set!" statement on every cell push on the scrolling menuand returning, never getting to the switch statement.

Comment: I am editing the posted code above with your suggested technique. I had to make a couple of corrections to make it compile as you will see. Again...it is not getting past the error message in the guard block.

Comment: That means that the `filterDelegate` property isn't getting set. Are you using a segue to display the child view controller from the master view controller? If not, you'll need to use some other method to set the filterDelegate.

Comment: I used a custom segue in storyboard from the main view controller to the collection view controller and gave it an ID in storyboard that I referenced in the code above. I thought that was all that was needed.